# convert a json object array to a json file

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, jakarta-ee

Here is the the json file.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "kasun",
      "position": "Software Engineer",
      "salary": "10000",
      "start_date": "2015/08/10",
      "office": "ABC",
      "extn": "100"
    } ,
    {
      "name": "Amal",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "10000",
      "start_date": "2015/08/10",
      "office": "DEF",
      "extn": "100"
    }     
  ]
}
}
```

in my project i have to get this json file through a servlet file.
Now i have implement it.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, ParseException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String filePath = "D:\\yakaari\\EPIC_PROJECTS\\2015\\IBWEB\\IBWeb\\web\\datagrid.json";
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);
            JSONArray jsonarray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("data");
            session.setAttribute("jsonarray", jsonarray);

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("The " + i + " element of the array: " + jsonarray.get(i));
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/customer/customergrid.jsp");/*redirect to the login page*/

        rd.include(request, response);
    }
```

Now thw question is i want to convert this json object array to a json file again because i need a json file type variable to the ajax function.

This is the ajax function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#example').dataTable({
                    "ajax": "datagrid.json",

                    "columns": [
                        {"data": "name"},
                        {"data": "position"},
                        {"data": "office"},
                        {"data": "extn"},
                        {"data": "start_date"},
                        {"data": "salary"}
                    ]
                    ,
                    responsive: true
                });
            });
        </script>
```

is it can be done or are there any other way ? Thanks

Comment: Do you want to save your JSON response in a folder as json file and read it again in ajax?

Comment: Don't think to complicated. The JSON will be requested in a different HTTP request than the jsp itself. There is no need to "get it through the (same) servlet" However, JSON is nothing but plain text. Maybe you are looking for sth like this: http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/servlet-code-to-download-text-file-from-website-java/

Comment: @PraveenMP : No i didnt want to save the json file - thanks for the comment mate